# How do I count the amount of cups consumed and store the total water amount consumed in an array?

Tags: java, android

I am receiving a string, which I convert to an integer that contains the water level in mL. I am displaying the water level in a textbox, and showing it's progress in a progress bar. I need to count the amount of cups consumed in cupcount, each cup being 400ml, and store the amount of water consumed in cup_amount.

```
String text = new String(txValue, "UTF-8");
                            /* listAdapter.add(text);
                             messageListView.smoothScrollToPosition(listAdapter.getCount()-1); */
                             String[] parts = text.split(",");
                             String part1 = parts[0];
                             String part2 = parts[1];
                             temperature.setText("Temperature: " + part1 + " °F");
                             capacitance.setText("Water Level: " + part2 + " mL");

                                     int number = 0;
                                     try{
                                         number= Integer.parseInt(part2);
                                     }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

                                     }



                                    progressBar.setProgress(number);


                                int array[] = new int[200];
                               int cup_amount=0;
                             for(int a =0;a<array.length;a++) {
                                     array[a] = number;

                                     if(array[a]>0)
                                         cup_amount = array[a]-array[a-1];
                                        if(cup_amount >= 400)
                                        {
                                            cupcount= cupcount + 1;
                                            cup_amount=0;

                                        }
                                        Log.d("Array","arr: "+ Arrays.toString(array));

                                  }

                             cup_count.setText("Water intake = " + cupcount + " cups");

                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                         }

                     }
```

The problem is cup_count is not updating when the water level changes by at least 400mL. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, my expected input is the integer, 'number', that updates as the water level increases, it will be somewhere from 0mL to 500mL.

I am trying to record the amount of cups of water consumed, which will occur if the user drinks 400mL or more, and store it in the variable 'cup_count' so I can display it to the EditText box 'cupcount' in XML. I also want to record the total amount of water consumed in mL so I can inform the user that they have not had enough water in a certain time period, this will be stored in the variable 'cup_amount'. I'm not even sure if using an array is the best way to store these values.

Comment: Why do you need to store it in array?

Comment: To record amount of water consumed, so I can tell the user to drink more water if they haven't had enough water in a certain time period.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, could you edit your q and add expected input and output.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this is what you try achieve, but here you go:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int total_amount = 2750;
        int cup_count = total_amount / 400;
        int remainder = total_amount % 400;

        System.out.println("Water intake = " + cup_count + " cups.\nRemainder = " + remainder + " ml.");
    }
}
```